# Mobile @media query not making container cover whole screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a survey page, with a `background-color: red` and a smaller container to hold survey contents, as in the example below from a desktop:

[image: desktop view of survey page]

Now, I have used these `@media` queries to attempt to make the white container cover the whole page on a phone (so the whole page is the white container, no red background)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #survey-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-height: 800px) {
  #survey-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    }
  }
```

Now, these queries have seemingly no effect on a mobile phone, giving me this page:

[image: mobile view of survey page]

Why is my container still not covering the whole page?

Full HTML code here, giants-survey.html page: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jdipasquale

Comment: What is the position declaration for `#survey-container`?

Comment: You have a rogue bracket above your media queries right after the font import that is causing the issue.  Also you'll need to move your media queries below the rest of the CSS for them to override default styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500) }
```

The bracket in the end of this font import caused the `@media` queries to not work, removing it and adding `min-width: 100%` made it work.